# Next item in collection/category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Hey I have museum app and there I have exhibits in categories.

> type_id - is Category ID.
>
> ex_id - is order of sightseeing - itn't primary key of exhibit

I have buttons to navigate to next and previous exhibit.

```
  <% if @exhibit.previous %>
    <%= link_to "", @exhibit.previous %>
  <% end %>
  <% if @exhibit.next %>
    <%= link_to "", @exhibit.next %>
  <% end %>
```

In model i have methods:

```
def next
    Exhibit.order("ex_id").where("type_id <= ?", type_id).first
  end

  def previous
    Exhibit.order("ex_id").where("type_id <= ?", type_id).last
  end
```

I want navigate throught category order by ex id. My code did't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you

```
def next
  Exhibit.where("ex_id > ? AND type_id = ?", ex_id, type_id).first
end

def previous
  Exhibit.where("ex_id < ? AND type_id = ?", ex_id, type_id).last
end
```

Comment: I have error: SQLite3::SQLException: near "<": syntax error: SELECT  "exhibits".* FROM "exhibits" WHERE (id < 632 AND < type_id = 53)  ORDER BY "exhibits"."id" DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: is ex_id your primary key ?

Comment: no ex_id isn't my primary key. it's order of sightseeing